# Should a date be added when displaying a quote from the mtg Comprehensive Rules

Tags: discussion

Since it seems to be quite common that when answering a question, a quote from the magic the gathering comprehensive rules is also included, can we adopt a common format for quoting from the rules?

**Can I have 1000 cards in my deck?**

Yes.

M:tG Comprehensive Rules (2012 Feb 1)

> 100.5. There is no maximum deck size.

(Note: I believe that previously there was a change to the rules that required that you were able to shuffle the deck unassisted)

Is it much of a concern, or does the CR not change often enough to need a date (do they move subsections around much, so that 100.5 will not be regarding **deck size** in the future?)

Comment: I believe the CR are revised with the release of each set, but mostly to reflect any new abilities in that set. Only a small fraction of the existing rules actually change in each revision, and of those changes, the majority occur in conjunction with the release of a core set (so, once a year). Plus they do try to maintain the numbering for existing rules.

Answer (score 5):

**This isn't necessary as every post is dated already.**  If an answer was posted 6 months ago, I wouldn't expect the information to be up to date without further checking.  This is a great reason to try to include the source of any answer so that folks can easily verify the ruling and decide for themselves how much to trust it.

Also, every game is subject to this to some extent.  It will happen to Magic much more often than most, but modern games are supported by online FAQ's and designers posting to various forums who often change rulings

Comment: Including the source also gives other people the opportunity to correct an out-of-date answer (or propose a correction if they don't have the rep themselves) or to post a correct one if the existing answer depends heavily on an old ruling.

Comment: @Dave - and also, other folks should ask about the source if it isn't clear from the answer.